# How to send message to socket io server from java

Tags: socket.io

Web client send this message (watched in chrome dev tool):

[image]

In server logs:

```
hello { limit: 10, safeSearch: true, orderBy: null, orderDesc: false }
```

I want send same from java with socket io client. I tired:

```
    JSONObject j = new JSONObject();
    j.put("limit", 10);
    j.put("safeSearch", true);
    j.put("orderBy", JSONObject.NULL);
    j.put("orderDesc", false);

    socket.emit("searchTorrent","hello", j);
```

But In server logs:

```
hello [Function]
```

(I don't have server and client code)

What's i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server expect ack function, so solution:

```
socket.emit("searchTorrent", "hello", j, (Ack) ack -> {});
```